# Facebook page post embed option missing

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a Facebook page and no matter if the page is published or not, I don't have the "embed" option in my posts. The IKEA page on the other hand has that option.

As I'm trying to display through javascript my posts as embed, I get the error that the post is not available, so I went to my page and saw that the "embed" option is missing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

What do I have to do to enable that option in my page?

[image]
The following represents the code I'm using to show the FB Post as embed:

```
$.each(response.posts, function(i, post)
{
    var html = '<div class="fb-post" data-href="' + post.permalink_url + '" data-width="200" data-show-text="true"></div>';

    $(container).append(html);
});

FB.XFBML.parse();
```

And to all my page posts I receive the following FB error:

[image]

## Edit:

It seems that only posts created through Graph API does not contain the embed option. I'm using the following code to create the Page posts:

```
$data = ['message' => 'Just testing', 'published' => TRUE];

$fb->post("$myPageId/feed", $data, $myPageToken);
```

And indeed the embed option does not appear in my facebook page, but according to the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/page/feed there is no param that I can use to enable the embed option.

When creating the post directly through my facebook page the embed option shows.

Comment: Is your page restricted in any way? Like country or age restricted?

Comment: @WizKid see my edit, it seems that is a issue related to the creation of post through API.

Comment: Is your app in live mode and has all necessary permissions approved in review?

Comment: @04FS no, its on development mode :|

Comment: Then any posts you create via it are only visible to users with a role in the app. They will not be visible to other users even directly on your Facebook page, and you can not embed them elsewhere either. You get no embed link in the UI, because this is not _supposed_ to work in the first place. You need to make your app live.

Comment: @04FS would you like to set that as a answer? Its correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its on development mode

Then any posts you create via it are only visible to users with a role in the app. They will not be visible to other users even directly on your Facebook page, and you can not embed them elsewhere either. You get no embed link in the UI in this situation, because this is not supposed to work in the first place.

You need to make your app live.